# vue 3 checkbox :checked binding

Tags: forms, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm rendering a form to update a bill, which is related to several orders. The point is, when I create a bill, in the backend all the related orders are set to true in a matched attribute. Then in the update form I need to load the orders based on the matched attribute value, just in case some of need to be removed.

Here the code:

```
<tr v-for="order in bill.orders" :key="order.id">
  <td>
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      :id="order.id"
      class="form-check"
      :checked="order.matched"
      v-model="bill.orders"
      :value="order.id">
  </td>
```

Comment: I want to load the checkboxes checked or not dependin of the value of the matched attribute of each one.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have a list of matched orders you can use `computed` to filter them:

```
<template>
    <tr v-for="order in matchedOrders" :key="order.id">
        <td>
            <input
                type="checkbox"
                :id="order.id"
                class="form-check"
                :checked="order.matched"
                v-model="bill.orders"
                :value="order.id">
        </td>
    </tr>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    computed: {
        matchedOrders() {
            return bill.orders.filter((order) => {
                return order.matched;
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```